# how to open a url in different browser in android instead of its builtin browser

Tags: android

Here is the code to open a url in android's built in browser

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com/pantherstechnik"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Now i want to show the dialog box or default dialog which contains browsers list which are currently installed on android device. May someone guide me how to do it.

Comment: http://onallthingsweb.wordpress.com/2014/01/31/launching-the-browser-in-android-with-xamarin/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have one browser application , the chooser will not launched , the URL will be loaded on that browser application. If you have two or more browser applications, the android system launch an `IntentChooser` the show the list of all browser apps installed on the device , so the user can choose his preferred browser to load the URL :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com/pantherstechnik"));
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent);
startActivity(chooser);
```

Comment: accept the answer if it worked for you..Happy coding!!

Answer (score -1):

You can trigger for the custom intent chooser like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com/pantherstechnik"));
```

Always use string resources for UI text. This says something like "Share this photo with"

```
String title = getResources().getText(R.string.chooser_title);
```

define the chooser title text in string.xml to use here.

Create and start the chooser

```
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, title);
startActivity(chooser);
```